# Show and tell (and show and tell!)

Tags: knowledge, anagram

The seven regions formed by the intersecting ellipses are each home to exactly one of the seven tiles.

Can you place the tiles so that those in each ellipse can be rearranged to solve the corresponding clue?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you (I am assuming it is you) post exact same puzzle on Reddit Puzzles too? https://www.reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/way7ic/show_and_tell/

Comment: It was more the other way round. I post daily on Reddit and weekly on the puzzles feed. Sometimes I publish the same ones here sometimes others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answers are:

> State: **MARYLAND**
> Show: **[HOMELAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeland_(TV_series))**
> Show and State: **[OKLAHOMA!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma!)**

So the diagram looks like this:

> [image]
>
> Although, [Maryland](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m0019g29) could be a show as well!

Comment: Arguably your "state" should be "[show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma!) and state" as well.

Comment: @Jafe true, and LukasRotter's deleted answer had Oklahoma as the show and state and not Maryland, so up to debate a bit. I've gone with my choice just based on the word 'show' where Maryland is definitely a TV show and not sure if musicals count as shows - who knows, OP might have meant the other order!

Comment: What Jafe said - the exclamation mark usage suggests to me that the 'show' in question is the stage show in his link, because that's how it's punctuated...

Comment: @Stiv hmm I think you're right, the exclamation has swayed me, changed it. Feel bad for Lukas now, he answered a few seconds after me, but probably had the intended answer!

Comment: Thinking you could also put the "ME" outside of the circles at the top, between "SHOW" and "STATE", and get a secret alternate answer of "Missouri"...

Comment: I’ll be honest my original answer was the musical show but my bad for not knowing the second variant